# regular expressions iphone

Tags: iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

How can I chceck on iPhone with regularexpressions NSStrring contain only this chars: `a-zA-Z` numbers `0-9` or specialchars: `!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:"|;'\<>?,./`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "] invertedSet];
NSString *stringValueOfTextField = [[searchBar.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] 
                                    componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

try this::::

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes you can use standard class [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
       regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\w[!@#$%^&*()_+-={}\[\]:\"|;'\<>?,./]"
                            options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                     options:0
                                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Note that `NSRegularExpression` is only available on iOS 4 and above.